# Is Spring Boot WS SOAP endpoint able to works with reactive manner?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, reactive-programming

Let's say that my wsdl file says that this endpoint returns String but I want them to return Future or Mono. 
When I just changed the returned type this is what I've got:

```
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [public reactor.core.publisher.Mono&lt;java.lang.String&gt; example.QuestionEndpoint.questionEndpoint(java.lang.String)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
```

I've searched a lot of articles and forums and found only solutions for SOAP client.

```
@Endpoint
public class QuestionEndpoint {

   @PayloadRoot(namespace = http://stack.org/, localPart = "Question")
   @ResponsePayload
   public String questionEndpoint(@RequestPayload String request) {
      return facade.getQuestion(request)          
        .flatMap(result -> Mono.just(mapper.toDto(result)))
        .block();;
   }
}
```

In my code below endpoint I'm using Mono from 'reactor.core' and doing block() in endpoint just before return the result. Is it enough to work this endpoint in a reactive way?

If it's not enough, Is Spring Boot WS SOAP endpoint able to return some reactive type, even if my WSDL file require specific type? 
In REST API it's kinda easy to implement it in a reactive way.

Comment: can you share your wsdl?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't . I got it from client. I edited a question so please take a look again.

Comment: Spring WS doesn't have reactive support, so no. Also this code isn't reactive as you are calling `block` which is, as the name suggest, blocking.

Comment: @M.Deinum Does JAX-WS support it? I didn't find any info about it on thier page but maybe I missed something.

Comment: jax-ws is a standard not an implementation, but I highly doubt it as pre-dates reactive programming.

Comment: @JamesParson I never tried it, but there seems to be support in JAX-WS according to https://godatadriven.com/blog/reactive-web-service-client-with-jax-ws/. However you would have to touch the WSDL if I saw i t correctly.